# Deploying Front-end and Backend in same dyno on Heroku

Tags: node.js, vue.js, express, heroku

I am trying to deploy a vue.js client front-end (which has its own sub-directory and package.json file within) and an express js backend (which also has its own sub-directory and package.json file within), in a single dyno on Heroku. I have initialised git in the root directory. I am pushing the files using the following command:

```
git subtree push --prefix server heroku master
```

In the package.json of the server, I have tried several approach, including the following, to build the client app:

```
"heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install && npm run build"
"heroku-postbuild": "cd ./client && npm install && npm run build"
"heroku-postbuild": "cd ../client && npm install && npm run build"
"heroku-postbuild": "cd client npm install && cd client npm run build"
"heroku-postbuild": "cd ./client npm install && cd ./client npm run build"
"heroku-postbuild": "cd ../client npm install && cd ../client npm run build"
"heroku-postbuild": "npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
```

But always obtaining an error similar to:

```
can't cd to client/
```

The solutions proposed online are always one of the alternatives tested above, but do not actually work. How can I deploy an app having both a front-end and backend in their respective directories on Heroku?

Comment: You're explicitly pushing only the server subtree, the client directory's not on the Heroku remote _at all_.

Comment: @jonrsharpe How should I push both then? If I try to push at the root level, Heroku will complain that it cannot find the package.json file in the root folder.

Comment: _Don't_ push the subtree? Fundamentally your repo's not well set up for Heroku, which will need a root package.json for buildpack detection; either have a third one that coordinates the other two, move the server one up to the root, or merge client and server to a single one.

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe I will try this, but it appears that others were able to deploy using a similar structure.